# TYPO3 and MySQL trigger

Tags: mysql, typo3

In ext_tables.sql file of an extension I can define new tables/fields that are going to be added to the database.

Is it possible with TYPO3 to add also Triggers (MySQL) to database?

Answer (score 0):

Not via `ext_tables.sql`.

You can use the extension manager signal slot and execute your queries there after installation of your extension

`ext_localconf.php` of your extension:

```
call_user_func(function($extensionKey) {
        $signalSlotDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\SignalSlot\Dispatcher::class);
        $signalSlotDispatcher->connect(
            \TYPO3\CMS\Extensionmanager\Service\ExtensionManagementService::class,
            'hasInstalledExtensions',
            function($keyOfInstalledExtension) use ($extensionKey) {
                if ($extensionKey !== $keyOfInstalledExtension) {
                    return;
                }
                \Vendor\MyExt\Hooks\ExtensionManager::postInstallExtension();
            }
        );
    }
}, $_EXTKEY);
```

Comment: Thank you but installing and uninstalling extension is not very convinient when you deal with stage/dev environments and you need to think about every time new installation is created.